# Change tab character width in iTerm2

Tags: macos, iterm2

The tab character in iTerm2 seems to be rendered as 8 spaces by default. Is there any way to change this to, say, 2 or 4? I didn't find anything in the iTerm2 preferences or documentation.

Answer (score 6):

You can find this setting in iTerm preferences under `Advanced > Terminal` (section header)

The setting name is `Default tab stop width for new sessions` and the default value is indeed `8`.

[image: Screenshot of iTerm2 preferences]

For reference, I am running iTerm Build 3.3.8 beta 5.

Answer (score 1):

The [`tabs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tabs&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=Darwin+8.0.1%2Fppc&arch=default&format=html) program can do this (changing the behavior of the *terminal*).  For example

```
tabs -2
```

to set the tab interval to **2**.  This is a fairly standard feature of VT100s (actually ECMA-48) which iTerm2 appears to support.  Here is a screenshot for iTerm2 from a test-script which uses `tabs` and `tput` (written to investigate a deficiency in *another* terminal emulator):
[image]

However, programs (such as vi) are not aware of this change, so the result may not be satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. As you alluded to, I think this only affects the behavior of the native Terminal program and not iTerm2, unfortunately.

Comment: This worked for me in iTerm2 FWIW